# Adding a list of numbers inside of a for loop

Tags: python, list

I had a task to sum the square of first 100 natural numbers, but I keep running into the problem -

> 'int' object is not iterable.

I have tried to make the list as a string or the sum as an int, but it did not work. I am a beginner so I would appreciate any help!

```
y=0
x=0
for z in range(1, 10000):
    while y<100:
        x=((y+1)**2)
        y=y+1
    a=sum(z)
    print (a)
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops?

Comment: Because `z` is an integer, and you are trying to get the sum of it.

Comment: Lots of answers use `range()`, just be aware that `range(100)` does _not_ include 100 itself. So you'll have to think about whether 'natural numbers' includes 0 or not (the ISO definition does).

Answer (score 4):

A more pythonic way:

```
s = sum(x**2 for x in range(100))
```

Comment: Ha.  I was just about to post this **exact** answer - nice one!  +1

Comment: Definitely more pythonic :D

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because the `sum` function needs an iterable. You're passing it an int, which won't work. For more info about this, check the [official documentation on the sum function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

For your code to work, you only need one loop.

```
result = 0
for x in range(101):
    result += x*x

print(result)
```

As [@kwinkunks mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919619/adding-a-list-of-numbers-inside-of-a-for-loop/57919679#comment102257503_57919619), the range should go to 101 as it represents the stop argument and is not iterated in the loop. Check the [official documentation about range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) for more info.

This should output:

```
338350
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the sum of the square first 100 natural numbers you can do it with just one loop

```
total=0
for i in range(1,101):
    total +=i*i
print(total)
```

this will output as

`338350`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` and `lambda` functions.

```py
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y**2, range(1,101)))
```